# Variables in Kv language (kivy)

Tags: kivy

My Kivy Language file has many font_size properties, all with same values, is there away where I can assign a variable in KV lang?
Current KV file sample:

```
#User ID
    Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: 20
        text_size: self.size

    TextInput:
        id: userid
        font_size: 20


    #User PW
    Label:
        text: 'Password'
        font_size: 20
        text_size: self.size

    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
        font_size: 20

    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        font_size: 20
```

Is is possible to set it somewhat like this:

```
#User ID
    @fs: 20
    Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: fs
        text_size: self.size

    TextInput:
    id: userid
    font_size: fs


#User PW
Label:
    text: 'Password'
    font_size: fs
    text_size: self.size

TextInput:
    id: password
    password: True
    font_size: fs

Button:
    text: 'Login'
    font_size: fs
```

By doing so, I would be able to change the font size at once only by changing the FS variable value, also, similar solution might help me to create theme based files faster.  Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I would be able to change the font size at once only by changing the FS variable value,

You can set a value with `#:set name value`, but this isn't quite what you want. Since you want the variable to update, you should use a kivy property so that the event system takes care of it for you.

In this case, since you want lots of different things to depend on size like that, you could for instance use a property of your app class.

```
class YourApp(App):
    font_size = NumericProperty(20)
```

then in kv

```
font_size: app.font_size
```

Any changes to the font_size of the App instance will then automatically propagate to these kv rules.

Comment: Follow up, can font_size be inherited from a parent widget? If multiple text or label widgets are nested in a grid, can I just set font_size on the grid?

Comment: You can inherit either explicitly by adding for each one a rule like in the answer above (except using an id and `font_size: id_name.font_size` for each widget), or abstract this behaviour in a new class that binds to its parent't font_size.

Comment: What's the difference between `NumericProperty` and `int`?

Comment: @Pyzard https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html

Comment: Is it possible to use expressions in set? e.g `#: set newval (otherval + offset)`  (i tried but get parser error)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way. What you are looking for is this expression:

```
#:set name value
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

Your .kv file:

```
#User ID
    #:fs 20
    Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: fs
        text_size: self.size

    TextInput:
    id: userid
    font_size: fs


#User PW
Label:
    text: 'Password'
    font_size: fs
    text_size: self.size

TextInput:
    id: password
    password: True
    font_size: fs

Button:
    text: 'Login'
    font_size: fs
```

Comment: Your kv file example should say #:set fs 20